# How to use angular component with ui-router?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to use `components` (instead of `controllers` and `templates`) in ui-router. But this isn't working.
I'm following [this](https://ui-router.github.io/tutorial/ng1/hellosolarsystem) article from their website.
[Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/obS47e2eexJe2PJXt8SI?p=info)

html:

```
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <h1>Help!</h1>
    <a ui-sref="mypage">mypage</a>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
  </body>
```

js:

```
// Register
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

// config
angular.module('myApp').config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state({
    name: 'mypage',
    url: '/mypage',
    component: "newComponent" // cant use this.
  })
});

//component
angular.module('myApp').component('newComponent', {
  template: "<h1> THis is from component <h1>"
});
```

I'm neither getting the result, nor any errors. What I'm missing here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: switch versions on right side of plunker and click libraries  [works fine here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Cpph8siwPTnJYf5ihniO?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the right version.

[Get the beta one](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/):

npm install --save angular-ui-router@1.0.0-beta.1